# Export mongodb data to json

Tags: python, json, mongodb, docker, pymongo

After running the `mongodb` docker image I created a database called `MovieFlix` and some collections with items inside the database.

What I want is to find a way to store all the data  from the `MovieFlix db`  in a  `json` file to have it saved for later user for docker-compose.

Should I do it with python code using `pymongo` or is there a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb has a [command line tool](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) for exporting to json or csv. The keyword for this is **dump**. Hope it helps!